# LazyInitializationException thrown from EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have created a EJB that is exposed as a web service (REST). However I get the exception below when I try it. I traced it down to my JPA annotations on the Question entity. It seems like it throws this exception when I uncomment the `@ManyToOne` mapping (the one with the fetch attribute). I have at purpose made all the relationships that the entity may have with other entities to `FetchType.LAZY`. And I want to keep it that way.

I am using container managed transactions and all the normal EJB glory. Why does this happen? And what are the fixes?

**EDIT:**
I have a repository class annotated with `@Stateless`, then I use this class in another EJB which retrieves a list of questions from the repository. Then at last I have a resource which is also annotated with `@Stateless`. Is it because of some persistence context or something?

**PS I have left out all other things from entity, the code works when I fix the annotations as described.**

```
@Entity
public class Question extends AbstractModel {

    private int id;
    private Participant participant;
    private List<Answer> answers;
    private List<QuestionCategory> categories;
    private List<QuestionFeedback> feedback;

    public Question() {
        answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
        categories = new ArrayList<QuestionCategory>();
        feedback = new ArrayList<QuestionFeedback>();
    }

    @ManyToOne
    //@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParticipantId")
    public Participant getParticipant() {
        return participant;
    }

    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionId", nullable = false)
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "QuestionQuestionCategory",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionId", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionCategoryId", nullable = false)
    )
    public List<QuestionCategory> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionId", nullable = false)
    public List<QuestionFeedback> getFeedback() {
        return feedback;
    }
}
```

Throws this exception:

> [#|2012-11-11T00:10:59.182+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=71;_ThreadName=Thread-8;|StandardWrapperValve[javax.ws.rs.core.Application]:
>   PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application
>   threw exception org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:272)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.get(Accessor.java:354)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor.getUnadapted(Accessor.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.hasValue(TransducedAccessor.java:251)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:105)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONMarshaller.marshallToJSON(BaseJSONMarshaller.java:103)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.writeTo(JSONRootElementProvider.java:143)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:157)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.*handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.*_invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) |#]

Comment: The stack trace indicates that you must turn that entity to `FetchType.EAGAR`.

Comment: I already know that, @ManyToOne is defaulted to FetchType.EAGER. But why is this needed? Isn't everything running in transactions etc?

Comment: You might have attempted to access the child entity (a lazily initialized entity) which hadn't yet been initialized that could be populated if and only if it's annotated by `FetchType.EAGAR` (if not defaulted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the exact problems that Andy is. What I found out till now is:

```
@ManyToOne
//@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ParticipantId")
public Participant getParticipant() {
    return participant;
}
```

You **can** set `LAZY` to single attribute associations, but you shouldn't. Leave the `@ManyToOne` annotation there:

> Lazy attribute fetching: an attribute or single valued association is
>   fetched when the instance variable is accessed. **This approach requires
>   buildtime bytecode instrumentation and is rarely necessary.**

As for the `Collections` I have added `Hibernate.initialize(categories)` like this:

> Sometimes a proxy or collection needs to be initialized **before closing
>   the Session.** You can force initialization by calling cat.getSex() or
>   cat.getKittens().size(), for example. However, this can be confusing
>   to readers of the code and it is not convenient for generic code. The
>   static methods Hibernate.initialize() and Hibernate.isInitialized(),
>   provide the application with a convenient way of working with lazily
>   initialized collections or proxies. Hibernate.initialize(cat) will
>   force the initialization of a proxy, cat, as long **as its Session is
>   still open.** Hibernate.initialize( cat.getKittens() ) has a similar
>   effect for the collection of kittens.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "QuestionQuestionCategory",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionId", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionCategoryId", nullable = false)
)
public List<QuestionCategory> getCategories() {
    Hibernate.initialize(categories)
    return categories;
}
```

And now I have an `org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session` exception. According to the bolded text, the session should be open. I still can't find a way to start a session in a container-managed app. Just calling `getCategories()` does not do the trick of proxy nor session initialization.

Any tips?

**Edit: Solution**

Probably you want to load the associated collection when the user clicks something and then an action or actionListener is fired.

What you have to do is (and please, this is very generic):

- Implement a `find(Object id)` method with the `Hibernate.initialize()` method (remove it from the `getCategories()` method in the snippet above):

  ```
  public Question find(Object id) {
      Question question = getEntityManager().find(Question.class, id);
      Hibernate.initialize(question.getCategories());
      Hibernate.initialize(question.getAnswers());
      Hibernate.initialize(question.getFeedback());

      return question ;
  }
  ```
- Search the entity when the view requests the loading:

  ```
  public void userHasClickedAQuestion(Object id) {
      selectedQuestion = questionFacade.find(id);
  }
  ```

And you are done. Your answers, questions and feedbacks will be loaded and shown when you call the getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

`LazyInitializationException`: After `Session`(Otherwise : `EntityManager`) has been close, the entity of its will be **detached**. The problem, the collection of object(`QuestionFeedback`, `QuestionCategory` and `Answer`) is detached. if you use `lazy=false`(Otherwise : `FetchType.EAGER`) in `hibernate`, the collection of object will be loaded in memory even if `Session` is closed.

Reference : [Hibernate: Understanding Lazy Fetching](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html)

Comment: So, what is the solution. Setting all relationship to eager? Doesn't that seem a little stupid?